# Save caller identity in .listen() in dart

Tags: dart

I'm making several websockets that will be handled by single annonymous functions:

```
handleWebSocketCreation(WebSocket socket) {
  connections[++current_connections] = socket;
  socket.listen((String s) => print("Client $current_connections sent: $s"), onDone: () {
    print('Client $current_connections disconnected');
  });
}
```

That obviously doesn't works as expected (it will keep printing the greater the *current_connections* value it has whichever the socket has sent rather than the actual id of the same)

Any workaround that could output like this?:

> Client 3 sent: hello
>
> Client 1 sent: hi, 3!
>
> Client 2 disconnected
>
> etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to capture the value of `current_connection` in a variable so you can use it later.

```dart
handleWebSocketCreation(WebSocket socket) {
  int id = ++currentConnections;
  connections[id] = socket;
  socket.listen((String s) { 
    print("Client $id sent: $s"); 
  }, onDone: () {
    print('Client $id disconnected');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A definitely not fancy one would be the next one:

```
socket.listen((String s){
  int id = connections.indexOf(socket);
  print("Client $id sent: $s");
})
```

However that takes lots of complications later, I would love some solution that makes static the current value of the *current_connections* variable at the time of making the assignment in the .listen()